# Ediff: view whitespace differences

Tags: ediff

Is there a way to make Ediff highlight whitespace using a different color, the way it does for non-whitespace differences?

For example, here are two regions with only whitespace differences:

[image]

And here are two regions with non-whitespace differences:

[image]

The non-whitespace differences are highlighted with `ediff-fine-diff-*` faces, while whitespace differences are not. I'd like some way to tell *what* the whitespace differences are.

Comment: Make sure `ediff-diff-options` is not set to `"-w"`, which tells the `diff` program to ignore white space. May not solve the problem, but might help you get there.

Comment: I don't have `ediff-diff-options` set to `-w`. With your setup, are your whitespace differences highlighted?

Comment: No, not even after pressing `*` (`ediff-toggle-autorefine`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like this feature is simply not supported.

The highlighting of fine differences is referred to as ["refinement"](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/ediff/Refinement-of-Difference-Regions.html) by Ediff, and explicitly skips whitespace.

> Note that refinement ignores spaces, tabs, and newlines.

Answer (score 1):

One way you can do this is by enabling whitespace mode in all the ediff buffers.
This can be done by
<kbd>Meta</kbd> + <kbd>x</kbd> + <kbd>whitespace-mode</kbd>

It may be enough just to enable in the merge buffer. I'm not sure how you might go about enabling by default, but there will be a way.